# API for Google for Education last login data of users?

Tags: php, api, google-admin-sdk

I have a super admin privilege for google for education apps. I want to check if a specific user have already logged in to his/her account. I can manually do this admin console but i need to retrieve it using the web application that i created. I am just wondering if there's an API for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull `lastLoginTime` with the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user).

If you're looking to pull login data for all, you can also use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login). I would personally, recommend the Directory API over this though if you're looking for current data as it's not abnormal for the reports data to be a week old.

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps not completely secure approach, would be to use a standalone google appscript. Turn on the admin SDK both in the advanced Google service menu and in the API. Then you can make standard GET requests to the appscript. This way the admin authentication is handled by the appscript.

```
  function doGet(e) {     
  var email = e.parameter.email;
  var someinfo =  user.someinfo
  Logger.log(someinfo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(name); 
}
```